# Django: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_quantity_sum'

Tags: python, django

I've created a method in my models that checks the stock balance for my webshop app.

models.py:

```
class ProductVariantSize(models.Model):
    product_variant = models.ForeignKey('ProductVariant', related_name='sizes')
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size')
    available_qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %d kom' % (lang.resolve_dict(self.size.name), self.available_qty)

    def stock_check(self):
        from webshop.models import OrderDetail

        sold_sum = OrderDetail.objects.filter(
            variant=self.product_variant, size = self.size).aggregate(
            total_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['total_quantity']
        receipt_sum = ReceiptDetail.objects.filter(
            variant=self.product_variant, size = self.size).aggregate(
            total_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['total_quantity']
        bill_of_lading_sum = BillOfLadingDetail.objects.filter(
            variant=self.product_variant, size = self.size).aggregate(
            total_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['total_quantity']
        stock_return_sum = StockReturnDetail.objects.filter(
            variant=self.product_variant, size = self.size).aggregate(
            total_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['total_quantity']

        total_sum = receipt_sum - sold_sum - bill_of_lading_sum - stock_return_sum
        if self.available_qty != total_sum:
            return False
        return True
```

As you can see my queryset filters are all the same. I want to use django custom manager here, but I can't seem to get it working. Here's what I've tried:

```
class SumManager(models.Manager):
    def get_quantity_sum(self):
        qs = self.get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(
            variant=self.product_variant, size = self.size).aggregate(
            total_quantity=Sum('quantity'))['total_quantity']


class ProductVariantSize(models.Model):
    product_variant = models.ForeignKey('ProductVariant', related_name='sizes')
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size')
    available_qty = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = SumManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %d kom' % (lang.resolve_dict(self.size.name), self.available_qty)

    def stock_check(self):
        from webshop.models import OrderDetail

        sold_sum = OrderDetail.objects.get_quantity_sum()
        receipt_sum = ReceiptDetail.objects.get_quantity_sum()
        bill_of_lading_sum = BillOfLadingDetail.objects.get_quantity_sum()
        stock_return_sum = StockReturnDetail.objects.get_quantity_sum()

        total_sum = receipt_sum - sold_sum - bill_of_lading_sum - stock_return_sum
        if self.available_qty != total_sum:
            return False
        return True
```

I keep getting the following error:

> 'Manager' object has no attribute 'get_quantity_sum'

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, it it not?: You do not have the Manager in place that you want to use. You need to assign it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your custom manager on the model that you want to use it on. So in your code, you defined `objects = SumManager()` on `ProductVariantSize`, however you are trying to call the `SumManager`'s method `get_quantity_sum()` on all the other models (for example `OrderDetail`).

If you wanted to call `OrderDetail.objects.get_quantity_sum()`, you would need to define your custom manager on `OrderDetail`

Comment: Ty, when when I added objects = SumManager() to every model of details that I use it worked like a charm.